# WCF and List Generics<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, generics

I am creating a WCF service for running queries to the database.

```
class ServiceManager : IServiceManager
{
    public IList<T> ExecuteDataReader<T>(ParametersEL parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int ExecuteNonQuery(ParametersEL parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ExecuteScalar(ParametersEL parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Transaccion(List<string> querys, List<SqlParameterCollection> lstParams)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But when you run the service generates this error.

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: The type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1 [T]' can not be exported as type of scheme, because it is an open generic type. You can only export a generic type if all parameters are generic types of real rates.
```

This is the WCF interface

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IServiceManager
{
    [OperationContract]
    IList<T> ExecuteDataReader<T>(ParametersEL parameters);

    [OperationContract]
    int ExecuteNonQuery(ParametersEL parameters);

    [OperationContract]
    object ExecuteScalar(ParametersEL parameters);

    [OperationContract]
    Boolean Transaccion(List<String> querys, List<SqlParameterCollection> lstParams);
}
```

Please can someone tell me why this error and how to correct or some solution to pass this generic list  by the WCF. The idea is to be generic for any entity to use this OperationContract

Comment: Change it from `IList<T>` to `T[]` and return `list.ToArray()`. It doesn't make sense to return an `IList<T>` from a WCF method.

Comment: If I use the Array to pass data through the WCF as I can assign the List <T> to Array ??